# Is it worth the effort to split up in layer 3 with point to point links?

Tags: routing, layer2, layer3, point-to-point

I have this technical question.
With my family we have a little business. I got to provide internet access to three places, separated a few hundred meters each other. I need to allow to watch the surveillance DVRs in the private networks. For that I have two ISP connections at one of the places, two point-to-point air links, and some existing equipment like routers and switches. I have no much margin for buying new equipment. My question is, is it better to separate in layer-3 (IP) the three places, with static routing?, or leave it all in layer-2 with switches?
[image: net layouts]

my fear is, with only switches (layer2 routing) the air links can be too flooded up with broadcast LAN packets, which can degrade performance, since the whole layout is a broadcast domain itself. also I have to mention there can be noise or interference in the two air-links, because i have no much altitude available. the surrounding tall buildings in the neighborhood DO NOT allow me to use other configuration of air routes.

Is it better Scenario 1 or 2? Or perhaps other setup? Is it worth the effort to separate all places in layer3 with static routing? What do you think?
Thank you guys.

Comment: Welcome to network engineering.  You seem to know already why you should consider using L3 links.  But only you can determine if it is worth the trouble or expense.  Sadly, I'm voting to close as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: user below gave me an answer that is not an opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you'll be better off with the network-per-site arrangement.

- The routers are responsible for getting it to where it should go
- They can block/throttle/log as appropriate when things go wrong
- Very little change if you add another internet link
- Very little change to structure if you add another site
- Much easier to add redundant links
- Much easier to isolate/contain problems to single sites

As a comment on your addressing:

- Consider using smaller than /24 for the point-to-point links
- Consider using a different block altogether for point-to-point links